# GCM to FCM migrate. Firebase not working. Unregistered registration token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, dagger

I try to migrate from GCM to FCM. I read this [guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm). I clone code from [firebase quikstart app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) everything works great. But if I try to implement in my app I have a ploblem.

I try to send several messages from firebase console and status some of them "Completed" but I receive nothing in my app... Excluding the first few messages I get all the time: Unregistered registration token. For sending I use token from FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() 
[image: firebase dashboard]

I don't uderstand that is problem.

my InstanceIdService:

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService
        extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Inject
    FCMTokenProvider FCMTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        application.getComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String newToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    FCMTokenProvider.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

my FirebaseMessagingService:

```
@EService
public class FcmMessageListenerService
    extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Inject
MessageDispatcher messageDispatcher;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    application.getComponent().inject(this);
}



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
            MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();


    if(application == null)
        return;

    if (message == null)
        return;

    String from = message.getFrom();

    Map<String, String> stringData = message.getData();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    for(String key: stringData.keySet()){
        data.putString(key, stringData.get(key));
    }
    messageDispatcher.handleMessage(from, data,application.getCurrentActivity());
}
}
```

part of my Manifest:

```
<application>
...
<service
   android:name=".infrastructure.fcm.services.FcmMessageListenerService_">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
   android:name=".infrastructure.fcm.services.MyInstanceIDListenerService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
...
</application>
```

part of my build.gradle:

```
def GcmVersion = '10.2.1'
...
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$GcmVersion"

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$GcmVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$GcmVersion"
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I had one problem with the old version of Dagger 2 and Firebase. I just updated the version of Dagger 2 to 2.9

I will be grateful for any help.

**UPDATE**

my renamed and updated GCMTokenProvider:

```
@Singleton
public class FCMTokenProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "FCMTokenProvider";

    private String fcmToken;

    @Inject
    public FCMTokenProvider(){

    }

    public void initialize(Context applicationContext){
            this.fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(fcmToken)){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new FcmToken(fcmToken));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "run: fcm token: "+ fcmToken);
    }

    public String getFcmToken() {
        return fcmToken;
    }

}
```

initialize() is called on every app start.

Comment: Does `onTokenRefresh()` trigger?

Comment: @AL I check it. I think no, but I don't uderstand why...

Comment: @AL I add my TokenProvider. I call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() on every app start and use recieved token in firebase console.
I thought the token does not change for a long time. In my quickstart app token does not change for a week and messages are accepted.

Comment: Hi Viktor. What's odd to me is how the quickstart works fine for you, yet the app doesn't. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with [tag:dagger] to comment or answer accurately. Nonetheless, have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the app before testing again?

Comment: Thanks, AL. Yes, several times I deleted the project. Every time I install, I get a new token and it does not work (

Comment: Just now I reinstall my app. I removed my FCMTokenProvider and I recieve token by onTokenRefresh(), I try to send message from firebase console and it status "Completed" but I recieve no messages in app and now all my messages "Failed" ...

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. 
In the beginning I was getting the error when I call

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken():

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process it.clipcall.another. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I fix it by add in onCreate Application exetended class

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context);
```

This was a big mistake!

I received a token, but when I sent the first message in the console I got the status "Completed", but received nothing in the application. When sending the following messages, the token was not registered. I could not understand what was the matter.

Now I have deleted all the libraries from my application and now I'm not getting an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in ..."  my app works fine until I start adding libraries. 
I found that there is an incompatibility between the versions of support and firebase lib versions.

Now I  use

```
gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

for find hide support dependencies and exlude module or group support.